# No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/
HTTP ERROR 404

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace CMS.WEBAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("controller")]    
    public class CoursesController: ControllerBase
    {
        public CoursesController()
        {

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetCourses()
        {

            return "hello world";
        }
        
    }
}
```

--

getting error as pagenot found

Answer (score 0):

by changing the route attribute - working fine.
**[Route("controller")]**